# Extending Exceptions with module-specific prefix, intended for parsing error reporting

Tags: python, parsing, exception

For one of my [WIP] project, I extended the dictionary class a lot with specific handlers, as such I determined that I wanted `KeyError` and `TypeError` exceptions to be specific to my project's parser. I extended the exception class like this:

[Github Permalink](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/blob/6a089845b2385bb755b364c44fec7da68a344634/libvmf/exception.py)

```
"""Exception classes
"""

class ValveException(Exception):
    """Base Exception
    """
    pass

class ValveKeyError(ValveException):
    """KeyError specific to map parsing
    """
    pass

class ValveTypeError(ValveException):
    """TypeError specific to map parsing
    """
    pass
```

Exceptions are raised by either the recursive parser loop, or by the extended dictionaries when they are given a key that is not whitlisted:

[Permalink](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/blob/6a089845b2385bb755b364c44fec7da68a344634/libvmf/parse.py#L95)

```
if not datatype in self.datatypes:
    raise ValveKeyError(
        "Unknown datatype [ %s ]"
        % datatype
    )
...
```

[Permalink](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/blob/6a089845b2385bb755b364c44fec7da68a344634/libvmf/datatype/base.py#L16)

```
if not hasattr(self, vmf_key):
    raise ValveKeyError(
        'Key `%s` not allowed in %s'
        % (key, self._type())
    )
...
```

[Permalink](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/blob/6a089845b2385bb755b364c44fec7da68a344634/libvmf/datatype/base.py#L24)

```
if not value[0].allow_multiple:
    raise ValveTypeError(
        "Type %s does not allow allow multiple values"
        % (type(value[0]))
    )
...
```

[Permalink](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/blob/6a089845b2385bb755b364c44fec7da68a344634/libvmf/datatype/base.py#L43)

```
if any([
    value is None,
    not type(value)(allowedcontainer(value)) == value
]):
    # We do not get the same value, we cannont cast
    raise ValveTypeError(
        ("Illigal Type %s for key `%s`, "
        + "expected Type %s for value `%s`") % (
            type(value), key, allowedcontainer, value
        )
    )
...
```

And Lastly, the exception handler:

[Permalink](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/blob/6a089845b2385bb755b364c44fec7da68a344634/libvmf/parse.py#L112)

```
except ValveException as err:
    self._parseerrors.append(
        'Ln %s: %s' % (self.i, err)
    )
```

Which works for me and I am content to leave it alone; This lets me `except MyTypeError` and `except MyKeyError` as to distinguish between a parsing problem, and a coding problem.

Is this distinction between Coding Fault, and Parsing Fault a good distinction to have? I don't know if I feel comfortable using the native `KeyError` and `TypeError`s in place, not until I was absolutely sure that there were no ways they could be a coding fault, as that might cause exception routes to handle bad parser input handle a coding exception.

Thoughts and insights are welcome, as well as constructive criticism regarding the post's subject matter.

> *[edit] Added Exceptions Raise calls (with links), as requested.*

*Note: The revision posted was non-stable, I have since published a revision that at least can run [[d8bf9f18]](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/tree/d8bf9f1898d6676bc6f427ad88d8ac14d94c61eb) Though it is widely irrelevant to the question posed in this thread.*

Comment: Well, exception classes all by themselves don't mean much. Where do you throw them? Under what circumstances? Please add enough context for reviewers to actually be able to *review* your code - as for the permalink, [please see this meta post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1309/23788).